# JSF commandlink incorrect navigation

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

Before asking this questions I have carefully assessed the feasibility to solve the following problem.

I have an external link being fired from an email `viewRequest.xhtml?requestID=6`. I use a filter to intercept the incoming request and in case the user is not authenticated it is forwarded to the `login.xhtml` page. After the user is authenticated the request is forwarded by `FacesContext.getCurrentInstane().getExternalContext().redirect(redirected-url)` Then it displays the page successfully.

Now if try to logout from same page i.e, `viewRequest.xhtml` page, the requested URI is `viewRequest.xhtml` again which takes me to the same page instead of logging out and redirect me to the login page.

I have the real concern of why the `request.getRequestedURI` in filter is still `viewRequest.xhtml` instead of `login.xhtml`

**Code for reference**

*AuthenticationFilter - User is un-authenticated - Adding requested email link in session*

```
String from = req.getRequestURI();
if (req.getQueryString() != null) from += "?" + req.getQueryString();
req.getSession().setAttribute("from", from);
res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/pages/login.xhtml");
```

*After user is logged in*

```
if (from != null && !from.isEmpty()) {
    externalContext.getSessionMap().remove("from");
    externalContext.redirect(from); *-----------Original URL re-direction---------*
    return null;
}
else{
       result = "adminHome";
    }
```

*Now we are in viewRequest.xhtml page - loaded successfully - Now clicked on Log out*

```
String from = req.getRequestURI();   <!--FILTER-->
```

The value of `requestedURI` is still `viewRequest.xhtml`

*logout() in LoginController.java*

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
return login;
```

Please help. Thank you very much.